# find out match word and display the position of it from the array values using php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a set of array data i need to find out the match word from that values of array

```
$my_word = 'mbusa.com';

$array_data = array:6 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "Mercedes-Benz Luxury Cars: Sedans, SUVs, Coupes and Wagons"
    1 => "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mbusa.com%2Fmercedes%2Findex"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => "Mercedes-Benz - International Corporate Website"
    1 => "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mercedes%2Dbenz.com%2F"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    0 => "New Mercedes-Benz Cars - Autotrader"
    1 => "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.autotrader.com%2FMercedes%2BBenz%2Dcars.jsp"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    0 => "Mercedes-Benz C-Class - mbusa.com"
    1 => "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mbusa.com%2Fmercedes%2Fvehicles"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    0 => "Mercedes-Benz - New models: Pricing, MPG, and Ratings | Cars.com"
    1 => "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cars.com%2Fresearch%2Fmercedes_benz%2F"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [
    0 => "Mercedes-Benz Reviews - Mercedes-Benz Cars | Edmunds"
    1 => "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.edmunds.com%2Fmercedes%2Dbenz%2F"
  ]
  6 => array:2 [
    0 => "Mercedes-Benz - Wikipedia"
    1 => "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMercedes%2DBenz"
  ]
  ]
```

In this array , i need to find that my_word and need to display the position `mbusa.com found at N position`.

I m trying with the below code

```
$matches = array_filter($array_data, function($var) use ($my_word){ 

  return preg_match("/\b$my_word\b/i", $var); 

});
```

But it is giving error like

> preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Any suggestions please ?

Thank you .

Comment: Iterate over $array_data and compare values of $my_word and $array_data[i][1]. I am not sure of the exact syntax in php.

Comment: N postition means??

Comment: i need to know the position where the myword matches

Comment: @Anant yes i m checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
foreach ($array_data as $key=>$val){
     foreach ($val as $key1=>$v){
        if(strpos($v,$my_word)!==false){
          echo 'match position is $array_data['.$key."][".$key1."]";
          echo PHP_EOL;
        }
     }
 }
```

Output:- https://eval.in/745846

Comment: 5367683   glad to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help . one more small concern here in the code my url is coming like `/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mbusa.com%2Fmercedes%2Findex`  but my actual url is `https://www.mbusa.com/mercedes/index` . But how to do i print this as in actual format on my view . Suggestions Please.

Comment: Got it .Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

This way you can do this:

```
$count = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_data); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($array_data[$i]); $j++) {
        if (strpos($array_data[$i][$j], 'mbusa') !== false) {
            echo "Found at Postion ".$j."<br>";
            echo $count++;
        }
    }
}
echo "Found " . $count . "Times";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strpos function which is used to find the occurrence of one string inside other:

```
$text = "/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mbusa.com%2Fmercedes%2Findex";

if (strpos($text, 'mbusa') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: I need to run through entire array .